# 4K TV as monitor in Kubuntu - display offset

Tags: kubuntu, hdmi, monitor, tv

My lounge media computer recently started being used as a web development platform so I put Kubuntu on, 19.10.  It is offsetting the display on an LG 4K TV UJ635V through an Nvidia 1030.  Offset is all the way round, about the width of a mouse-pointer, under native resolution (3840 x 2160) and 1080p.  No problem when display sent via Intel.  Using Nvidia's proprietary drivers.  All connections are HDMI.

Full details of my unusual configuration, just in case any of it is relevant.  Dual-booting Windows 10.  Kubuntu is a fresh install.  Nvidia 1030 card is providing 4k video (and audio) to TV, but also Intel providing audio output via a 7.1 AV-receiver.  Receiver can't relay above 1080p so I'd rather not pass-through.  For audio to work (at least in Windows), Intel feeds AV stream in to the receiver and the video output of that is ignored (unless I want to edit the BIOS).  Sometimes, the problem with offset display is apparent in Windows so it seems inherent in something, probably the TV not being a proper monitor, but it fixes in Windows by flicking from 4k to 1080p and back again.

The reason I'm not putting everything through the AV receiver is, it can't relay 4k.  TV is capable of 10bit colour, but it's not something I'm bothered about in Linux.

(I suppose I could always VirtualBox my Kubuntu.)

Pointers appreciated :)